# c# set two flags with one flag together

Tags: c#

At the time I have 2 buttons for two flags.
I want 1 button that set two flags

These are the flags:

```
if (InteractiveInput.Checked) flags |= CONNECT_INTERACTIVE;
if (PromptInput.Checked) flags |= CONNECT_PROMPT;
```

I want:

```
if (InteractiveInput.Checked) flags |= CONNECT_INTERACTIVE & CONNECT_PROMPT;'''
```

Comment: Use bitwise OR, not AND: CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitwise AND (&) means the combination for each bit where both are 1.
For enum flag values this usually gives 0/None because except for special cases, enum flag values are deliberately unique (bitwise) and as such have no bits matching with other enum values.

You want Bitwise OR:

```
if (InteractiveInput.Checked)
    flags |= CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT;
```

Imagine the following example:

```
[Flags]
public enum AdditionalCarParts
{
    None,
    AirConditioning,
    Sunroof,
    RearDoors
}
```

This is implicity defined as:

```
[Flags]
public enum AdditionalCarParts
{
    None = 0,
    AirConditioning = 1,
    Sunroof = 2,
    RearDoors = 4
}
```

Or in binary:

```
  0
  1
 10
100
```

As you can see, none of these have a bit that match, and therefore AND will never return anything other than None(0).

Two examples of combining them bitwise using the different operators:

```
AirConditioning (decimal: 1, binary: 001) & Sunroof (decimal: 2, binary: 010) = None (decimal: 0, binary: 000)  

AirConditioning (decimal: 1, binary: 001) | Sunroof (decimal: 2, binary: 010) = AirConditioning | Sunroof (decimal: 3, binary: 011)
```